# Get joomla page loading time

Tags: php, performance, time, joomla

I'm new to Joomla and I would like to get page loading time in order to log it and make stats.

In which file can I put le starting time catcher?
In which file can I put le ending time catcher?

thanks for your help

JS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to read [ask] and then [edit] your question to make it fit the guidelines: Show us what you have tried, describe what exactly you want to measure (time the server spends assembling the page?, time the browser spends rendering the page?, ...) and by what means you want to achieve your goal. Currently, given the information you have provided, there isn't much we can do for you because this is simply too broad as there are tons of possible metrics and solutions here.

Comment: Joomla 3.9 already includes profiling in its debugging option.

Comment: ok but i don't want to be in debug mode and want to profile user_id, loading time, url and user profil group

Comment: @Jean-Sylvain if you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask all of your Joomla questions there.  Also note, that `thanks for your help JS` is not relevant to researchers or volunteers, so that sign-off text should never be included in any question.